# Много форм с Symfony3

Tags: symfony, forms, symfony3

Пишу приложение в котором есть таблица. Нужно ее редактировать при помощи ajax. В каждом ряде таблицы находятся формы, чтобы можно было их отправлять на сервер. С помощью html форм все получается, но наверно лучше было бы использовать именно формы Symfony. Пытался реализовать формы симфони, но так и не понял как передать туда переменные. Так вот, как реализовать вывод многих симфони форм с разными параметрами? Таблица сейчас выводится вот так:

```html
<table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Rows</th>
                    <th>Change</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for garden in gardens %}
                    <tr id="editRow{{ garden.id }}">
                        <form method="POST" name="garden" id="saveRow{{ garden.id }}" action="javascript:void(null);" >
                            <input type="hidden" value="{{ garden.id }}" name="id" />
                            <td><input type="text" name="name" value="{{ garden.name }}"  class="table-inputs" readonly></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="rows" value="{{ garden.rows }}"  class="table-inputs" readonly></td>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <button id="{{ garden.id }}" class="btn btn-default btn-icon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-original-title="Edit"></button>
                                    <button id="{{ garden.id }}" class="btn btn-default btn-icon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-original-title="Delete"></button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </form>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать коллекции форм, почитать о них можно в  [документации](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).

Реализовать можно примерно так:

- создаём класс-контейнер для коллекции классов Garden:

// src/AppBundle/Entity/Gardens.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Gardens
{   
    protected $gardens;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->gardens = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getGardens()
    {
        return $this->gardens;
    }
}
```

- сам класс Garden:

// src/AppBundle/Entity/Garden.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Garden
{
    private $name;

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

- создаём форму для Garden:

// src/AppBundle/Form/Type/GardenType.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class GardenType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Garden',
        ));
    }
}
```

- создаём форму для Gardens:

// src/AppBundle/Form/Type/GardensType.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class GardensType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {   
        $builder->add('gardens', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => GardenType::class
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Gardens',
        ));
    }
}
```

- контроллер:

// src/AppBundle/Controller/GardensController.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Gardens;
use AppBundle\Entity\Garden;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\GardensType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class GardensController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $gardens = new Gardens();

        $garden1 = new Garden();
        $garden1->setName('garden1');
        $gardens->getGardens()->add($garden1);
        $garden2 = new Garden();
        $garden2->setName('garden2');
        $gardens->getGardens()->add($garden2);

        $form = $this->createForm(GardensType::class, $gardens);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Gardens:index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

- рисуем форму:

  {# src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Gardens/index.html.twig #}

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    
        {% for garden in form.gardens %}
            {{ form_row(garden.name) }}
        {% endfor %}
     
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/90993)

Comment: @cheops дополнил ответ